# Typesetting numbers above, below, left, and right of a symbol

Tags: math-mode

What commands would be the best way to put numbers above, below, left, and right of a symbol in math-mode, as in the following image:

[image]

Would the tensor package be useful here, or possibly another package? Thank you.

## Edit:

It looks like David's `\mathop` workaround works for display style, but not inline math mode. How would one fix it to work for inline, or perhaps use two different commands for inline and display mode?

Secondly, how would I shrink the size of the numbers with respect to the central symbol?

Comment: WRT your edit: `\displaystyle`.

Answer (score 15):

[image]

this uses `\mathop` to get symbols centred on the math axis then `{ }` to remove the extra horizontal spacing that `\mathop` introduces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}

\[{\mathop{\scriptstyle n}}{\mathop{\mathfrak{A}}\limits_m^p}{\mathop{\scriptstyle q}}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @IanMontague I did wonder if you wanted all four numbers to be `\scriptscriptstyle` rather than `\scriptstyle` a bit hard to tell from the original image

Comment: I'm not quite sure - the image was taken from page 9 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.0155.pdf

Comment: @IanMontague if it's arxiv can't you download the tex source?

Comment: I simply do not understand why you don’t add `\limits`: I’m afraid i must withhold my upvote until you do so.

Comment: @GuM originally as I assumed such a notation would never be used inline (for similar reasons I didn't do a full `\mathchoice` version that works in subscripts etc, but since the OP asked for inline I added `\limits`...

Answer (score 14):

This seems to reproduce well the formula at page 9 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.0155.pdf

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\around}[5]{%
  % first is the center, then the letters from bottom in clockwise fashion
  \setbox\z@=\vbox{
    \hbox{\around@sss{#2}}
    \hbox{\around@sss{#3}$\m@th#1$\around@sss{#5}}
    \hbox{\around@sss{#4}}
  }%
  \hbox to \wd\z@{%
    \hss
    \vbox{\offinterlineskip\m@th\scriptspace=0pt
      \ialign{%
        \hfil##\hfil\cr
        \hidewidth\around@sss{#4}\hidewidth\cr
        \noalign{\kern1pt}
        \vtop{\ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr
          \raisebox{\fontdimen22\textfont2}{\around@sss{#3}}%
          $#1$%
          \raisebox{\fontdimen22\textfont2}{\around@sss{#5}}%
          \cr
          \noalign{\kern1pt}
          \hidewidth\around@sss{#2}\hidewidth\cr
        }}\cr
      }%
    }\hss
  }%
}
\newcommand{\around@sss}[1]{$\m@th\scriptscriptstyle#1$}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\around{\mathfrak{A}}{m}{n}{p}{q}\otimes\around{\mathfrak{A}}{m'}{q}{p'}{n'}
\to\around{\mathfrak{A}}{m+m'}{n}{p+p'}{n'}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Actually, the paper uses Ti*k*Z for the job. Compare the results, top line my macro, bottom line the paper's.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\putaround}[5]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.base),inner sep=0ex]
\node [label={[label distance=.15ex]below:$\scriptscriptstyle #2$},
 label={[label distance=-.1ex, text depth=0pt, text height=0.5ex]left:$\scriptscriptstyle #3$}, 
 label={[label distance=.15ex]above:$\scriptscriptstyle #4$},
 label={[label distance=-.1ex, text depth=0pt, text height=0.5ex]right:$\scriptscriptstyle #5$}] (A)
{$#1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\around}[5]{%
  % first is the center, then the letters from bottom in clockwise fashion
  \setbox\z@=\vbox{
    \hbox{\around@sss{#2}}
    \hbox{\around@sss{#3}$\m@th#1$\around@sss{#5}}
    \hbox{\around@sss{#4}}
  }%
  \hbox to \wd\z@{%
    \hss
    \vbox{\offinterlineskip\m@th\scriptspace=0pt
      \ialign{%
        \hfil##\hfil\cr
        \hidewidth\around@sss{#4}\hidewidth\cr
        \noalign{\kern1pt}
        \vtop{\ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr
          \raisebox{\fontdimen22\textfont2}{\around@sss{#3}}%
          $#1$%
          \raisebox{\fontdimen22\textfont2}{\around@sss{#5}}%
          \cr
          \noalign{\kern1pt}
          \hidewidth\around@sss{#2}\hidewidth\cr
        }}\cr
      }%
    }\hss
  }%
}
\newcommand{\around@sss}[1]{$\m@th\scriptscriptstyle#1$}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\around{\mathfrak{A}}{m}{n}{p}{q}\otimes\around{\mathfrak{A}}{m'}{q}{p'}{n'}
\to\around{\mathfrak{A}}{m+m'}{n}{p+p'}{n'}
\\
\putaround{\mathfrak{A}}{m}{n}{p}{q}\otimes\around{\mathfrak{A}}{m'}{q}{p'}{n'}
\to\putaround{\mathfrak{A}}{m+m'}{n}{p+p'}{n'}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although :correct", the lower "limit" *m* seems a bit tight.  Adding a bit of height (say `\vphantom{t}`) might improve the appearance.

Answer (score 6):

Using `stackrel` package + `\stackbin` option, you can obtain this:

**Note: This code is only for this combination of these characters because every another letters could be change the position of `n` and `q`.**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{stackrel}

\begin{document}
    $\stackbin[m]{p}{\mathfrak{A}}\mkern-22mu{\scriptstyle n}{\phantom{aa}}\mkern-6mu{\scriptstyle q}$
\end{document}
```

Thus with this MWE you will have not any problems for the position of the characters.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{stackrel}
\begin{document}
    ${\scriptstyle n}\stackbin[m]{p}{\mathfrak{A}}{\scriptstyle q}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is using TikZ also, but somehow simpler egreg's answer. TikZ controls everything: the center and around symbol with their scaling and distance, as well as horizontal alignment with other texts or formulars (via option`baseline=(A.mid)`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,tikz}
\newcommand{\putaround}[8]{%
% #1 center char
% #2 scale rate of center char
% #3,4,5,6 around chars
% #7 scale rate of around char
% #8 distance from center to around
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.mid)]
\path
(0,0)     node[scale=#2] (A) {#1}
+(0:#8)   node[scale=#7]     {#3}
+(90:#8)  node[scale=#7]     {#4}
+(180:#8) node[scale=#7]     {#5}
+(270:#8) node[scale=#7]     {#6};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\begin{document}
This is inline symbol \putaround{$\mathfrak{A}$}{1}{$q$}{$p$}{$m$}{$n$}{.8}{.3}
 that TikZ controls everything: the center and around symbol with their scaling and distance, as well as horizontal alignment with other texts or formulars. And below is around symbol with display style 
\[
\putaround{$\mathfrak{A}$}{2}{$q$}{$p$}{$m$}{$n$}{1}{.6}
=\int_0^1 f(x) dx.
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Sebastiano It's my bad habit. Should we use `\[  ... \]` ,right?

Comment: Thanks! I changed to `\[ ... \]` as you suggested.

Comment: please keep it! others may learn from that

Comment: They were only simple comments :-( and not very important for your code.